# Auth0, error decoding access token with HS256 encrypt algorithm

Tags: python, auth0

I want to make a function that checks if the access token is valid using [Auth0](https://auth0.com) in *Python*.

Now, the token could be encrypted with *HS256* or *RS256* algorithms.

The next code works all fine with the **RS256** algorithms, but returns an **Exception: Expected a string value** with the other encrypt algorithms. Why?

```
def is_valid_token(access_token, audience, algorithms):
    AUTH0_DOMAIN = 'dev-47ysz721.auth0.com'

    jsonurl = req.urlopen('https://' + AUTH0_DOMAIN + '/.well-known/jwks.json')
    jwks = json.loads(jsonurl.read())
    cert = '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n' + jwks['keys'][0]['x5c'][0] + '\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----'
    certificate = load_pem_x509_certificate(cert.encode('utf-8'), default_backend())
    public_key = certificate.public_key()

    try:
        decoded = jwt.decode(access_token, public_key, audience=audience, algorithms=algorithms)
    except Exception as e:
        print 'Excepcion', e
        return None
    return decoded
```

**Edit:**

- The params *access_token*, *audience* and *algorithms* are all **strings**, so the problem is not there.
- Removing the *try except* the full traceback is the next:

  ```
  Traceback:
  File "/home/vagrant/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
    111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
    57.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py" in view
    87.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
    466.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/vagrant/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
    463.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "./apim/viewsets.py" in list
    144.             decoded = is_valid_token(access_token, account, audience, algorithms)
  File "./apim/viewsets.py" in is_valid_token
    50.     decoded = jwt.decode(access_token, public_key, audience=audience, algorithms=algorithms)
  File "/home/vagrant/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jwt/api_jwt.py" in decode
    92.             jwt, key=key, algorithms=algorithms, options=options, **kwargs
  File "/home/vagrant/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jwt/api_jws.py" in decode
    156.                                    key, algorithms)
  File "/home/vagrant/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jwt/api_jws.py" in _verify_signature
    220.             key = alg_obj.prepare_key(key)
  File "/home/vagrant/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jwt/algorithms.py" in prepare_key
    140.         key = force_bytes(key)
  File "/home/vagrant/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jwt/utils.py" in force_bytes
    30.         raise TypeError(&#39;Expected a string value&#39;)

  Exception Type: TypeError at /ventasapi/v1/HS.json/
  Exception Value: Expected a string value
  </textarea>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Share this traceback on a public Web site">
    </div>
  </form>
  </div>
  ```

Comment: Can you remove the try/except block and include the resulting full traceback?

Comment: @glibdud added the full traceback.

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution, not much recommended but work fine. is adding the paramenter *verify=False*, the result of the code is:

```
if algorithms=='HS256':
        decoded = jwt.decode(access_token, public_key, audience=audience, algorithms=[algorithms], verify=False)
else:
        decoded = jwt.decode(access_token, public_key, audience=audience, algorithms=[algorithms])
```

See: [verify](https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#reading-the-claimset-without-validation)